# DynamoDB filter expression for element in a list in Python

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries, filterexpression

I am trying to scan a DynamoDB table for records that have dates in a list of items before a certain date. Here is a sample record:

```
{
  "PK": "NYC",
  "SK": 500000,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "start": "2023-03-01T20:00:00",
      "end": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Sarah",
      "start": "2021-03-01T20:00:00",
      "end": "2022-03-01T20:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

For example, I want the scan to return records that have an end date before "2023-01-01T00:00:00".

I have tried:

```
scan_kwargs = {'FilterExpression': Attr('members').contains(Attr('end').lt("2023-01-01T00:00:00"))}
response = self.table.scan(**scan_kwargs)
```

That gives me a syntax error. I have also tried:

```
scan_kwargs = {'FilterExpression': Attr('members.end').lt("2023-01-01T00:00:00")}
```

But that gives me nothing back.

How can I write this to give me the correct records?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't actually want to check that `members.end` is less than a value; you want to check that any element `members[].end`<sup>1</sup> is less than that value, and DynamnoDB doesn't have that functionality. (Your document doesn't have an element `members.end`: it has `members[0].end` and `members[1].end`.)

Instead, you'll have to pull the data back and do the filtering at your application. This means you'll have to transfer more data and use a bit more CPU, but it won't cost you any more in DynamnoDB costs. Per the [scan documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression):

> A filter expression is applied after a `Scan` finishes but before the results are returned. Therefore, a `Scan` consumes the same amount of read capacity, regardless of whether a filter expression is present.

---

<sup>1: To be clear, this is not valid DynamoDB filter exprssion syntax. I'm borrowing syntax from `jq` to illustrate by analogy what the correct query might be, if DynamoDB supported it.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use contains on a list of maps by only passing a string value. To use contains, you'll have to pass the entire map value, not just a single element of it.